# Python Selenium: Unable to Discover Open Pages

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Error Like that:

```
\[2023-02-19 10:06:05,978\]: rw_rule_crawling.py:175 ERROR ERROR :  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Lion\\lion-admin\\tasks\\rw_rule_crawling.py", line 132, in get_pending_rule
driver = init_driver()
File "c:\\Lion\\lion-admin\\tasks\\rw_rule_crawling.py", line 28, in init_driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
File "D:\\Users\\zhanni\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome\\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME\['browserName'\], "goog",
File "D:\\Users\\zhanni\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromium\\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
File "D:\\Users\\zhanni\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 266, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "D:\\Users\\zhanni\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 357, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "D:\\Users\\zhanni\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "D:\\Users\\zhanni\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
(No symbol) \[0x00C837D3\]
(No symbol) \[0x00C18B81\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B1B36D\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B3ED6D\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B39B90\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B36FC9\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B71ED5\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B71B2C\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B6B216\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B40D97\]
(No symbol) \[0x00B4253D\]
GetHandleVerifier \[0x00EFABF2+2510930\]
GetHandleVerifier \[0x00F28EC1+2700065\]
GetHandleVerifier \[0x00F2C86C+2714828\]
GetHandleVerifier \[0x00D33480+645344\]
(No symbol) \[0x00C20FD2\]
(No symbol) \[0x00C26C68\]
(No symbol) \[0x00C26D4B\]
(No symbol) \[0x00C30D6B\]
BaseThreadInitThunk \[0x75C700F9+25\]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath \[0x773E7BBE+286\]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath \[0x773E7B8E+238\]
```

I try to add the `--no-sandbox` argument to ChromeOptions solved the problem,but the problem still there.  But it was good before. Then I found that there has an option :

```
chrome_user_data = os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + r"\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data
```

So I try to go to the Google folder. It's gone!!!!
I guess it should be a system update or chrome browser automatic update changed the location, so I deleted this option and it succeeded`

Comment: So please describe what's not working as supposed.